# How to invoking a function on a variant without casting

Tags: c++, variant

I have three classes, whereas an attribute of the first class can be the type of any of the other classes:

```
#include<variant>   

class A {
   public:
   std::string to_string(){
       return var.to_string();
   }
   std::variant<B,C> var;
};

class D {
   virtual std::string to_string();
};

class B : public D {
   public:
   std::string to_string();
};

class C : public D {
   public:
   std::string to_string();
};
```

I want to invoke a method (lets say to_string) on the member of class A. I know that every variant has an implementation of the function.

The most effective I have come up with is from cppreference:

```
 if(const B* b = std::get_if<B>(&var))
          b->to_string(); 
 if(const C* c = std::get_if<C>(&var))
          c->to_string();
```

Especially when working with many variants, this seems ineffectiv and ugly and I am thinking that this should be possible with a one-liner. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In this case, since you know both `B` and `C` inherit from `D`, is `std::variant` really necessary?

Comment: The simplest solution to the situation as currently shown would be to just have a pointer/smart-pointer to a `D` and thereby make use of `to_string` being `virtual`. But if you don't want to do that, then what exactly are the constraints for finding a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, since `C` and `B` inherit from `D`, you can just store a `std::unique_ptr<D>` (it has to be a pointer in order to get dynamic dispatch with object slicing). But if your real-world program has some constraints that prevent this from being viable, then your best friend when it comes to `std::variant` is [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

`std::visit` takes two arguments: a visitor and a variant. The visitor has to be an object of some form which is callable (i.e. has `operator()` defined) for each variant option (in your case, `B` and `C`). Then it calls the appropriate `operator()` for whatever is *actually* in the `std::variant`.

We *could* make a new class that defines all of these callables for us. It'd be tedious.

```
class MyCallable {

  std::string operator()(B& arg) {
    return arg.to_string();
  }

  std::string operator()(C& arg) {
    return arg.to_string();
  }

};

...

std::visit(MyCallable(), var)
```

(Note: If you make `to_string` on `D` a `const` method then you can take a `const T&` rather than an lvalue reference, which is probably better here)

But that's silly and incredibly verbose. We could also template it. That cuts down on the boilerplate a bit.

```
class MyCallable {

  template <typename T>
  std::string operator()(T& arg) {
    return arg.to_string();
  }

};

...

std::visit(MyCallable(), var)
```

That's a bit better, but it's silly that we have to define a whole class for this. Fortunately, modern C++ will let you define lambdas which have templated `operator()`, just like this but inline. So you can simply do this

```
std::visit([](auto& x) { return x.to_string(); }, var)
```

This will work for *any* `std::variant`, provided all variant options have a compatible `to_string` method (they don't even have to come from the same superclass; they can be unrelated `to_string` methods).